# Measure customers bandwidth

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, flash

I work with a mobile product and I want to get more insight into my customers bandwidth. I prefer to have a non-flash based solution as it can't run on iPhone.

I thought about writing something bespoke in JS that downloaded some bytes and just tracked the time to finish it.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You're thinking in the right direction.

Comment: To get a meaningful bandwidth measurement, you have to download a large amount of data. Keep in mind that many mobile users have payment plans with limited data per month. These people would certainly not appreciate you using up their data cap, unless you have a good reason to do so. Also, mobile users are constantly switching between different networks with vastly different bandwidths (edge, 3g, hsdpa, wifi...), so a bandwidth measurement from 5 minutes ago can already be meaningless.

Comment: @Philipp Only if they're driving, which they shouldn't be using their phone anyway. If simson is testing bandwidth I suspect it's because he's going to send a large block of data; making the quick 1 mb transfer totally necessary to determine feasibility. I'd say it's totally okay to do a network test for a session if it's for some reason necessary.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Even while not moving at all my phone likes to jump between edge and 3g all the time. I blame the phone company, but is not rare to happen. 1mb can be very slow but I thinks it's a good amount to test bandwidth. Alerting the user before doing it could be nice too

Comment: Yes dialog with users is always important before transferring a large amount of data

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: What about people using their cellphones on the train, on the bus, as passengers in a car or just while walking? There is a reason it's called *mobile* app and not *stationary* app. I also made the same experience as Pablo González Alba: My cellphone sometimes switches back and forth between edge and 3g even when I am just sitting somewhere. Also, 3g bandwidth depends a lot on how many people in the same cellular network cell are currently transfering data, which can fluctuate a lot.

Comment: Well then your transfer will reflect that and Simon will know to wait a bit and try again when your connection is the proper speed. Why would he want to transfer when the connection is spotty if he can help it? The exact things you're proposing will cause complications are the exact things he's LOOKING for to prevent causing complications when it's legitimate important data being transferred.

Very interesting though, I either have HSPA+ or nothing where I live and it is not spotty at all. Are you in a rural or metropolitan area? [nexus 4, North Carolina]

Comment: Also I do not believe the user will blame the app if they have a spotty network, they will likely blame the telecom company. He just wants to make sure that the average speed through the spots is fast enough to make things feasible.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jsbandwidth/